# How can I check what added the ppa?

Tags: 16.04, apt, nvidia, ppa

Running sudo apt-get update gives me the errors below. I am told it is because of something called ppa. **How can I check what added the ppa or where it came from so I can remove it if I don't need it ?**

My latest one was downloading CUDA 8.0 https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive

```
(test1) user@user-P15SM:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  Release [574 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  Release [574 B]
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease                
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:6 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:9 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Ign:10 http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial InRelease           
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release
Get:12 http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial Release [2,419 B]
Get:13 http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial Release.gpg [833 B]
Ign:13 http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial Release.gpg
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Hit:15 http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial/universe Sources
Hit:16 http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Hit:17 http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_SG
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                       
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                           
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                                                            
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                                                                             
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_SG                                                                                                        
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                                                                           
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                    
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                       
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                           
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                                                            
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                                                                             
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_SG
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_SG
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_SG
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_SG
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 3,252 B in 30s (108 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7A80C8ED4FCCBE09
W: The repository 'http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/xenial xenial Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: Users add PPA's - refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu, so if a PPA was added to your system it was added by a user of your system. If a user can't be trusted, they shouldn't have administrative (*sudo*) rights to add PPA's as they lack the same oversight or validation that occurs for .deb packages (thus reduce stability, security in order to gain extra functionality). I always use commands so I'd check my `history` to see when I added a repo/ppa (by default date/time isn't stored, but adding it is one of the first changes I make), next I'd try logs in /var/log/apt/..

Comment: Related: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: @guiverc, basically correct, but some software comes as `.deb` or `.sh` script that does not include the software itself, but only adds a repository, and installs itself from there. So the user has installed the `ppa`, but may ne be aware of it, and the `history` won't help then.